# passing props into vue2 component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a very simple `vue` component I'm using that I want to pass information into via props. In the HTML it looks like:

```
<myapp v-bind:source-key="some_key" v-bind:destination-key="some_other_key"></myapp>
```

The component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card card-default">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['sourceKey', 'destinationKey'],
        mounted() {
            this.$http.get('/map/' + sourceKey + '/' + destinationKey)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.dir(response)
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.dir(error);
                });
            console.log('got here')
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'd expect this would set the props `sourceKey` equal to `some_key` and `destinationKey` equal to `some_other_key` in the component, but I'm getting errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "some_key" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

So it seems like the expected value is being treated as the key? Then there's more errors saying that the `sourceKey` variable was never defined:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: sourceKey is not defined"
```

Where do I define the props, if not in the `props` block?

Comment: `this.$http.get('/map/' + sourceKey + '/' + destinationKey)` in that line you must access your props with `this` keyword (`this.sourceKey`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In parent's template:

```
<myapp v-bind:source-key="some_key" v-bind:destination-key="some_other_key"></myapp>
```

You get the error:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "some_key" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Because the parent does not have `some_key` in its `data()`.

In child:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: sourceKey is not defined"

You get an error because inside the Vue instance functions, the **prop**s must be referenced using `this`.

See a demo correcting both errors below.

```js
Vue.component('myapp', {
  template: "#myAppTemplate",
  props: ['sourceKey', 'destinationKey'],
  mounted() {
    this.$http.get('/map/' + this.sourceKey + '/' + this.destinationKey) // this fixes "ReferenceError: sourceKey is not defined"
      .then(function(response) {
        console.dir(response)
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.dir(error);
      });
    console.log('got here')
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    some_key: 'aaa',       // this fixes [Vue warn]: Property or method "some_key" is not defined
    some_other_key: 'bbb'  // this fixes [Vue warn]: Property or method "some_other_key" is not defined
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.4.0"></script>

<div id="app">
  <myapp v-bind:source-key="some_key" v-bind:destination-key="some_other_key"></myapp>
</div>

<template id="myAppTemplate">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card card-default">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here: `this.$http.get('/map/' + sourceKey + '/' + destinationKey)`

In `<script>`, you need to access `this.sourceKey` and `this.destinationKey`, to specify you want the properties off the Vue instance (and not variables defined elsewhere). You can only leave off `this.` in templates.

As for your first error, make sure `some_key` and `some_other_key` are variables defined in your Vue instance, under `data() { ... }`, computed properties, and so on, as the error message suggests.

Comment: I don't understand why `some_key` and `some_other_key` would need to be defined, since they would be the values assigned to the `sourceKey` and `destinationKey` props?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I meant to make sure they're defined _in the parent_, the one that's rendering the `<myapp />` component. The warning is there to guard against typoes and such.

Comment: Thanks-- your answer helped me with the second part, but I'm still not able to pass in `some_key` as the value of the `sourceKey` prop using this code